# Shopware 6. Config save post process

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to post process when my module's configuration is saved.

i tried

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return ['system_config.written' => 'onSaveConfig'];
    }
```

but this is fired once for each parameter of the configuration, and what I need is for it to be executed when all the configuration of my module has been saved.

I need it to work on all versions of shopware 6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific event triggered that suits your use case, but what you could do is to create a event listener on [symfonys `kernel.response` event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-response). There you could check that the correct controller was called, in your case probably the `\Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\Api\SystemConfigController::saveConfiguration()` or the `batchSaveConfiguration()` in the same controller, and check if the request contained the system configs from your plugin.